# Why isn't JavaScript displaying the text box value on page

Tags: javascript, html

I Want the code to get the **number** the **user** has **entered** and **display** it on the screen. I know that its just a dumb mistake that I have made.

```js
function run() {
  const quest = document.getElementById('quest');
  const data = quest.value;
  const element = document.createElement('div').innerHTML = data
  const store = document.getElementById('store');
  store.appendChild(element)
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Calucator</h1>
<input type="number" name="" id="quest">
<button onclick="run()">=</button>
<div id="store"></div>
```

Comment: `const element = document.createElement('div').innerHTML = data` <-- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: BTW, use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` - otherwise you'll introduce an XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments in your question pointed - `document.createElement('div').innerHTML = data` is not a document node element

And use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` - otherwise you'll introduce an XSS vulnerability.

```js
function run() {
    const quest = document.getElementById("quest");
    const data = quest.value;
    const yourElement = document.createElement("div");
    yourElement.textContent = data
    const store = document.getElementById("store");
    store.appendChild(yourElement);
}
```

What i changed in the function?

I first create the element, and then set it's text content. Finally i append it to the element you wanted.